# CPLEX Error 1016: Restricted version

Tags: c#-4.0, cplex

I have developed an app using C#  which loads a Cplex model to resolve a linear system (or program if it's spelled so).
the problem that I get is the error motioned in the title.
but when I try solving a problem using  the model in Opl studio 9.0 it works fine.
I don't know if the version is limited or there is a problem with C#.
if there is any one who could I help I'll appreciate it.
is there any way I can load a Cplex model from C# without filling it up manually (by code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at examples in Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Preview1251\cplex\examples